# React event.target.value.slice() undefined behavior?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the `<select>` tag in React with the `value` attribute that I get from state (Hooks). For my `onChange` handler, I call a function that uses `slice()` on `event.target.value`. Using `slice()` means that the `value` attribute never updates on the DOM.

Moreover, when I set `value` to `event.target.value.slice(0, event.target.value.length)`, the DOM updates correctly, but when I set it to `event.target.value.slice(1, event.target.value.length)` or any non-zero start index, the DOM doesn't update. No errors or warnings appear in the console and everything behaves normally (except for the DOM).

I have a minimal working example of this on a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-value-not-changing-0xplx

The critical part is:

```
<select
        name={"Feed Selector"}
        value={selectedFeed}
        onChange={event => onSelect(event, CHARS_TO_SLICE)}
>
  {selectOptions}
</select>
```

and my handler function is:

```
const onSelect = (event, charsToSlice) => {
    let toShow = event.target.value.slice(
      charsToSlice,
      event.target.value.length
    );
    setSelectedFeed(toShow);
  };
```

Why does slicing `event.target.value` affect my DOM? Since Javascript strings are immutable, `slice()` should return a string that I can fit into `value`.

Comment: does the `charsToSlice` value come from another input field?

Comment: @SultanH. right now, it's hardcoded into the `onChange` handler function call as an argument

Comment: you mean like `charsToSlice = 0`

Comment: @SultanH. `onChange={event => onSelect(event, 1)}` specifically, 1 can be changed to any length and the effect remains the same

Comment: Logic doesn't really make sense. Setting value for option that doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the chain of events:

- A selection is made
- onSelect callback runs
- `toShow` is set to e.g. `ong_feed1` (since the slice is 1 by default)
- React re-renders and the value is set to `ong_feed1`
- No options have a "value" property matching that value, so the DOM doesn't update.

So this is why the DOM doesn't update. If the DOM should update, the value needs to be set to something that matches an option that is present in the list of options.

It has nothing to do with mutating strings or whether or not slice is used etc.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. This is only matched against the `value` attribute of the `<option>`, right? So if I slice 5 chars and end up with `feed1` which is a valid label (but not a value), the DOM doesn't update?

Comment: Correct! It uses the value, not the label, to determine which item is currently selected.